# How to get Element data JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I do the deletion of my Document by `name = DocumentFile`
I'm trying to get href value and Delete using jQuery:

```
        <table id="docTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Document Uploaded</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in @Model.Document)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-route-fileName="@item.DocumentFile">@item.DocumentFile</a>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <form>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" id="DeleteHandleClick" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delModal">
                                <span class="material-icons">delete_forever</span>
                            </a>
                            <div>
                                <partial name="_DeleteForm"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

```
    <script>
    $('#docTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr','#DeleteHandleClick' , function () {
                    const doc = $(this).closest('tr').attr('documentFile');             
                    document.getElementById('handleDeleteClick').setAttribute("href", "Student/DeleteDocument/" + doc);
                    document.getElementById('modalTitle').innerText ="Are You Sure You Want To Remove This Document?";    
                });
    </script>
```

I meet an Error localhost:5001/Article/Details/Student/DeleteDocument/undefined

I use `getElementId` for my Partial View.

I created a form to confirm my deletion with a Partial View. I finished it with some Datatable views and I'm having trouble applying it to my view.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <i class="material-icons mx-auto" style="font-size:80px;color:red">error</i>
        <div id="modalTitle" class="modal-title bg-light text-dark badge bg-primary text-wrap" style="font-size:25px;"></div>
        <div id="modalWarning" class="modal-title badge bg-warning text-dark"></div>
        <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body badge bg-light text-dark text-wrap" style="font-size:15px;"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a id="handleDeleteClick" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Yes, Remove it!</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Why are you mixing javascript and jquery?

Comment: You can't repeat element ids in a page. They are unique by definition

Comment: `<a id="DeleteHandleClick"` ... `getElById("handleDeleteClick")` - maybe use the same IDs?  Or is this something that's not included in the question and you just like using highly confusing names?

Comment: I get Element id for `div` in partial view @charlietfl

Comment: @charlietfl is talking about `@foreach (..) { .. <a .. id="DeleteHandleClick"` will have multiple `a` with the same ID (as that's the only id= in the provided code.   Please read [mcve] and provide all the *relevant* code.

Comment: If partial has ids also then they will get duplicated since you load partial in loop

Comment: Sorry for this shortcoming, I updated my code again @freedomn-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
const doc = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:first a").text();
```

And I think you may put the partialview outside the loop

[image]

Comment: I have tried your way. I have selected the document I need to delete, but why is the href stuck together?
Error: localhost:5001/Article/Details/Student/DeleteDocument/

Comment: you can't get the doc value?

Comment: I have received value. It's just that I got mixed between two `a` tags so my href is wrong. Its true: localhost:5001/Student/DeleteDocument/...

Comment: I am looking for a solution

Comment: `It's just that I got mixed between two a tags so my href is wrong.` where are the two `a` tags, I just see one in the first `td` from your codes.

Comment: I was confused, I am trying another way, it only has 1

Comment: So you know the problem I'm having?

Comment: No, you can see my test in the post, the url address in the bottom-right corner which I think is correct.

Comment: I'm doing it in a `view` of `Article / Detail`

Comment: Maybe it got the href at the View Article / Detail I'm working on

Comment: I have solved the problem, thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to hear that!